# How inform SonarQube about a package rename?

Tags: sonarqube, rename, sonarqube5.1

After I renamed a Java package the SonarQube Preview shows me about +174 issues. About 150 of which already have been flagged as false-positives, but have been in another package back then.

(How) can I inform SonarQube about that package rename so that already flagged issues are recognized and do not pop-up again?

P.S.: I'm using SonarQube 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do confirm that this is a known limitation, see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-3321

Comment: What if I change the according _kee_ directly in DB-table _projects_?

Answer (score 2):

For [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) all `rename` and `move` actions are equivalent to the creation of new sources. Unfortunately you cannot associate these new sources with the old, so you need to mark those issues as False-Positives again.

---

[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) supports rename only for projects (with all components).

All components:

```
Project -> Settings -> Update Key
```

Single component:

```
Project -> Components -> (choose component) -> Settings -> Update Key
```

See [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) wiki: [Updating Project Key](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-UpdatingProjectKey)

Comment: This setting changes the project name of the whole project. I'm looking for a customization/rename of a single Java package within an existing project.

Comment: Ok, so `Project -> Components -> (choose component) -> Settings -> Update Key`

Comment: Nope. I only see 'Manual Measures' under Project -> Components -> <my Java package> -> Settings! No 'Update Key'. (That was something I tried at the very first). I'm using SQ 5.1 - does it make a difference?

Comment: I'm sorry, now I understood the question - unfortunately you cannot.